# when I run Firefox from 2 folders on Windows 7 why do I only get one firefox.exe process?

Tags: windows-7, process, firefox

I launched Firefox from normal folder, copy pasted Firefox folder from Program Files to my desktop and ran firefox.exe in desktop folder hoping to get two firefox.exe processes running at the same time. But, task manager does not show another process. How come?

Another interesting thing is that I can even delete this desktop folder after opening a Firefox window from its firefox.exe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the second invocation of Firefox is telling the first to open a new window. Pass `-no-remote` to the Firefox executable in order to override this, but be sure to use a separate profile as well if you do.

Comment: I see, thanks. Just tried this, but it popped up dialog "firefox process is already running" and refused to start another one. Oh well.

Comment: I already covered this. That's because you forgot to use a separate profile.